# Which MySQL JOIN and How...?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

Table 1 contains the User ID

Table 2 contains the user ID and other data I would like

The relationship is on the ID in both tables so what I would like to do is the following:

Pull all data from table 2 where a record exists in the id field in table 2 that matches an id in table 1.

Table 1 has other copies so to speak that are specific to other accounts while table 2 contains all the ids for all the other tables which is why (I think) I need a JOIN statement but I'm open to suggestions.

Table 1:

```
id
123456
```

Table 2:

```
id     | name  | age
123456 | John  | 23
651123 | Mary  | 22
811561 | Sarah | 21
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery as:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID
             FROM table1)
```

If you need fields from table1 as well then use an inner join like:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.name, t2.age
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, you need to join:

```
Select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.userid = table2.userid
```

The only question here is if you want to get only id's that appear on both tables (and than use `inner join`) or also get such that appear only on the first table as well (left join)

Answer (score 0):

You should choose inner join here because table 2 always contain records for table 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **INNER JOIN** here becuase you have relation between both table, query should be this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.name, t2.age
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON  t1.id = t2.id
```